# Is it possible to use eslint with Angular-CLI

Tags: angular-cli, eslint

I successfully configure eslint for node (npm run eslint); but I'm not able to configure Angular-CLI to use eslint with this configuration; it always uses tslint.

I've searched various online resources, but only found a hint that this might not be supported at all.

It is possible to achieve this, or am I stuck with tslint here?